# How can I load Avros in Spark using the schema on-board the Avro file(s)?

Tags: scala, hadoop, avro, apache-spark

I am running CDH 4.4 with Spark 0.9.0 from a Cloudera parcel.

I have a bunch of Avro files that were created via Pig's AvroStorage UDF. I want to load these files in Spark, using a generic record or the schema onboard the Avro files. So far I've tried this:

```
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import java.net.URI
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import java.io.File
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord}
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader
import org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput

val input = "hdfs://hivecluster2/securityx/web_proxy_mef/2014/05/29/22/part-m-00016.avro"
val inURI = new URI(input)
val inPath = new Path(inURI)

val fsInput = new FsInput(inPath, sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val reader =  new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord]
val dataFileReader = DataFileReader.openReader(fsInput, reader)
val schemaString = dataFileReader.getSchema

val buf = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[GenericRecord]
while(dataFileReader.hasNext)  {
  buf += dataFileReader.next
}
sc.parallelize(buf)
```

This works for one file, but it can't scale - I am loading all the data into local RAM and then distributing it across the spark nodes from there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord}
import org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import java.io.File
import java.net.URI

// spark-shell -usejavacp -classpath "*.jar"

val input = "hdfs://hivecluster2/securityx/web_proxy_mef/2014/05/29/22/part-m-00016.avro"

val jobConf= new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val rdd = sc.hadoopFile(
  input,
  classOf[org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]],
  classOf[org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper[GenericRecord]],
  classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
  10)
val f1 = rdd.first
val a = f1._1.datum
a.get("rawLog") // Access avro fields
```

Comment: This solution only works for one file at a time. I am having trouble getting hadoopRDD to work for more than one file.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/julianpeeters/simplesparkapp/tree/avro-generic) a maven project that can read multiple .avro files (tested on a Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.0). Not too sure about the relevant differences, but I note that your `SparkConf` may be different, as is your `JobConf`, and perhaps you need to set `    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, inPath)`? PS Happy vacationing, looking forward to the next installments.

Comment: i get 
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.mapred.{AvroInputFormat, AvroWrapper}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable

...
val path = "hdfs:///path/to/your/avro/folder"
val avroRDD = sc.hadoopFile[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]](path)
```

Comment: Getting

    scala> import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
    <console>:10: error: object generic is not a member of package org.apache.avro
           import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord

in Spark 1.0.2 and avro-1.7.7.jar, even though i see GenericRecord here: http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/java/ . What gives??

Comment: @matthieu you need to either set SPARK_CLASSPATH to include the location of avro.jar or include it with SparkContext.addJar("/path/to/avro.jar")

Comment: With the new versions you need to include hostname in the path so for example for my computer I use



`val path = "hdfs://localhost:9000//user/ganesh/default/bestsellingrank"`