# How can I read this avro file using spark & scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've seen various spark and avro questions (including [How can I load Avros in Spark using the schema on-board the Avro file(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944615/how-can-i-load-avros-in-spark-using-the-schema-on-board-the-avro-files)), but none of the solutions work for me with the following avro file:

http://www.4shared.com/file/SxnYcdgJce/sample.html

When I try to read the avro file using the solution above, I get errors about it not being serializable (spark java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper).

How can I set up spark 1.1.0 (using scala) to read this sample avro file?

-- update --

I've moved this to the mailing list: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-can-I-read-this-avro-file-using-spark-amp-scala-td19400.html

Comment: Did you collect them directly? You should map them to some Serializable classes since they cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to use spark 1.2 and sparkSQL as linked to in my question:

```
val person = sqlContext.avroFile("/tmp/person.avro")
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when trying to read an Avro file. The reason is that the AvroWrapper is not implementing `java.io.Serializable` interface.

The solution was to use `org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer`.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

val cfg = new SparkConf().setAppName("MySparkJob")
cfg.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
cfg.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "com.stackoverflow.Registrator")
```

However that wasn't enough, as my class, which was in the Avro file, didn't implement `Serializable` either.

Therefore I had added my own registrator, extending `KryoRegistrator`, and included [chill-avro](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter/chill-avro/0.5.0) library.

```
class Registrator extends KryoRegistrator {
  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo): Unit = {
    kryo.register(classOf[MyClassInAvroFile], AvroSerializer.SpecificRecordBinarySerializer[MyClassInAvroFile])
    kryo.register(classOf[AnotherClassInAvroFile], AvroSerializer.SpecificRecordBinarySerializer[AnotherClassInAvroFile])
  }
}
```

Then I was able to read a file like this:

```
ctx.hadoopFile("/path/to/the/avro/file.avro",
  classOf[AvroInputFormat[MyClassInAvroFile]],
  classOf[AvroWrapper[MyClassInAvroFile]],
  classOf[NullWritable]
).map(_._1.datum())
```

Comment: thank you for your sharing! why I always got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/chill/KryoInstantiator` ?

Comment: Did you add a dependency and included it in the final artifact?

Comment: Interesting enough. I tried package `com.twitter" % "chill-java" % "0.7.0"` but it doesn't work. only `0.7.1` version works. anyway, your solution is the only one works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Edit the serializer to be kryo should do the trick.

One way is to comment out the line in /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf:

> spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer