# Read an unsupported mix of union types from an Avro file in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I'm trying to switch from reading csv flat files to avro files on spark.
following https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro
I use:

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.avro("gs://logs.xyz.com/raw/2016/04/20/div1/div2/2016-04-20-08-28-35.UTC.blah-blah.avro")
```

and get

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This mix of union types is not supported (see README): ArrayBuffer(STRING)
```

the readme file states clearly:

> This library supports reading all Avro types, with the **exception of
>   complex union types**. It uses the following mapping from Avro types to
>   Spark SQL types:

when i try to textread the same file I can see the schema

```
val df = sc.textFile("gs://logs.xyz.com/raw/2016/04/20/div1/div2/2016-04-20-08-28-35.UTC.blah-blah.avro")
df.take(2).foreach(println)
```

> {"name":"log_record","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"request","type":{"type":"record","name":"request_data","fields":[{"name":"datetime","type":"string"},{"name":"ip","type":"string"},{"name":"host","type":"string"},{"name":"uri","type":"string"},{"name":"request_uri","type":"string"},{"name":"referer","type":"string"},{"name":"useragent","type":"string"}]}}
>
> <------- an excerpt of the full reply ------->

since I have little control on the format I'm getting these files in,
my question here is - **is there a workaround someone tested and can recommend?**

I use gc dataproc with

> MASTER=yarn-cluster spark-shell --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 4G  --executor-cores 4 --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1,com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0

any help would be greatly appreciated.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944615/how-can-i-load-avros-in-spark-using-the-schema-on-board-the-avro-files

Comment: you can use newHadoopApi for reading avro files - you'll need to use core api of spark and not sql-api. any special reason not to use it?

Answer (score 5):

You won't find any solution that works with Spark SQL. Every column in Spark has to contain values which can be represented as a single [`DataType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType) so complex union types are simply not representable with Spark `Dataframe`.

If you want to read data like this you should use RDD API and convert loaded data to `DataFrame` later.